# C# Read/Write Json Problem with current code

Tags: c#, json, list, unity-game-engine

**Error:** error CS0103: The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context

I have the latest Newtonsoft download and I cant figure out any way to fix this I've gone over about 50 different links all saying to install it. Which it is.

Am I missing something small? I am just trying to add my json elements to a list so I can use them in a program and then write back to the Json file. If this cant work can someone link or show me another way to do this in c#?

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Newtonsoft.Json {
public class CustomControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<string> controls;

    //public object JsonConvert { get; private set; }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LoadJson();
        for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(controls[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    public void LoadJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("CustomControls.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            controls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Newtonsoft assemblies in your project?

Comment: Try changing the namespace to something other than Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of the namespace in your code

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AnythingOtherThanNewtonsoft.Json {
public class CustomControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<string> controls;

    //public object JsonConvert { get; private set; }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LoadJson();
        for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(controls[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    public void LoadJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("CustomControls.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            controls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want or need to use Newtonsoft.Json for some reason, I highly recommend you this [guide](https://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/unity-and-nuget/).

Else, here is an alternative for your case, in which you can use unity`s JsonUtility.

You only need to wrap it in a class

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyControls{
    public List<string> controls;
}

public class CustomControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MyControls myControls;

    void Start()
    {
        SaveJson();
        LoadJson();
        for (int i = 0; i < myControls.controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(myControls.controls[i]);//No need to use ToString() here, it`s already a string
        }
    }

    public void SaveJson()
    {
        MyControls testControls = new MyControls() //Creates a new instance of MyControls
        {
            controls = new List<string>(2) {"a", "b"} //Your list of strings should go here.
        };

        File.WriteAllText("CustomControls.json", JsonUtility.ToJson(testControls)); 

    }

    public void LoadJson()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("CustomControls.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            myControls = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyControls>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added an example on how to save a json file using JsonUtility
The file created have this on it `{"controls":["a","b"]}`

Comment: This doesnt add anything to the myControls.controls

Comment: Did you try renaming your NameSpace

Comment: what do you mean by that, I deleted everything and copied and pasted to see if it would work, am I supposed to use a namespace with this like my code above?

Comment: it's very simple. Go to your original code where you have namespace Newtonsoft.json and change it to something else. The compiler is confused, because Newtonsoft already uses that namespace.

Comment: I tried with no namespace and with namespace System the count still is 0

Comment: Sorry, I guess I put this in the wrong thread. Changing the namespace will get rid of the issue you had to start with. The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention your file needs to be saved using a class. I will put a method that shows how to save a file as needed.

Comment: The example creates a json with this structure:
{"controls":["a","b"]}